# how to filters value reset after selecting using react - admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
const AssetsFilters = (props) => {
   return (
        <Filter {...props}>
          <ReferenceInput 
           alwaysOn={true} 
           label="Classification" 
           source="AssetClassificationID"
           reference="AssetClassification" >
           <SelectInput
           optionText="AssetClassificationName"
           emptyText="All" />
           </ReferenceInput>
         </Filter>
    )
};
export default AssetsFilters
```

how to reset the filter values after selecting give some solution.

Comment: There is a setFilters prop in your filter component, you can use it:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset filter values in react admin framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52926290/how-to-reset-filter-values-in-react-admin-framework)

Comment: ok, I will try that.

Comment: that does not work for me.

Comment: yes its work for me now Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const {
setFilters,
} = useListContext();

```
const resetFilter = () => {
    setFilters({}, []);
};
```

<Button onClick={() => props.setFilters({ })}>Reset